# Python import; ignore branch/trunk/tag layer

Tags: python, bash, svn, pythonpath

How can I hack `PYTHONPATH` as follows.

Currently I have

```
trunk/
   subproject1/
      __init__.py
      subsubproject/
          __init__.py
          module1.py
   subproject2/
   subproject3/
branch/ ...
tag/ ...
```

and so I just set `PYTHONPATH=trunk` and

```
import subproject1.subsubproject.module1
```

works as expected

However, the subprojects are becoming unwieldy.

I'd like

```
trunk/
   subproject1/
      # __init__.py # I imagine these may have to be sacrificed 
      subsubproject/
          trunk/
              module1.py
          branch/ ...
          tag/ ...
   subproject2/
   subproject3/
```

in a way that I can still use the same import statement, namely

```
import subproject1.subsubproject.module1
```

python preferable, but bash acceptable

I've been tinkering with `__init__.py` and `__all__` to no avail. I'll keep trying, but if someone has already done this, I'd appreciate the time saved.

Comment: Don't run your code directly from your source repository; install it to a temporary build directory first and import it from there.

Comment: @chepner in retrospect, your approach seems like the obvious answer, but given an adequate solution (`pkgutil`) and that i'm writing sysadmin scripts that are in constant development, am I shooting myself in the foot by continuing with my current approach?

Comment: Possibly. I can't judge the complexity of your scripts without seeing them, but it seems like a very good idea to separate your test suite from whatever source control system you are currently using.

Answer (score 0):

In the `__init__.py` of `trunk` in `subsubproject` add this line:

`from subproject1.subsubproject.trunk import module1`

That should allow you to import like you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ended up working for me (with the added feature that I can choose to load `trunk` or a specific `tag`/`branch` by setting an env var)

```
import os
from pkgutil import extend_path

_file_path, _file_name = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))[0]

_svn_ver = os.environ['SVN_VER'] if 'SVN_VER' in os.environ else 'trunk'
if 'SVN_VER%s' % _file_name in os.environ:
     _svn_ver = os.environ['SVN_VER%s' % _file_name]

__path__ = extend_path(__path__, os.path.join(_file_path, _svn_ver))
```

Python community has thought of everything, I love this language! I'll leave this question unanswered for a while to see if there is an even better solution.

**EDIT**

A couple of slight changes to the above, as certain imports were still not working

```
import os

_file_path, _file_name = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(__file__))

_svn_ver = os.environ['SVN_VER'] if 'SVN_VER' in os.environ else 'trunk'
if 'SVN_VER%s' % _file_name in os.environ:
     _svn_ver = os.environ['SVN_VER%s' % _file_name]

__path__ += [os.path.join(__path__[0], _svn_ver)]
execfile(os.path.join(_file_path, _svn_ver, '__init__.py'))
```

This code can be added into each directory that contains `branch`/`tag`/`trunk` and the `__init__.py` files within these (`branch`, etc.) will still be used.